# why my code doesnt work? i need to make a password generator,

Tags: python

when i chose 2 letters, 2 symbols and two numbers it works, but when i chose per example 40 numbers, 40 sybmols and 40 numbers, it doesnt work, say that

when i chose 2 letters, 2 symbols and two numbers it works, but each number dont work

say that:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 866, in 
symbols_password += symbols[random.randint(0,len(symbols))]
IndexError: list index out of range

it says that
this line is line isnt on the range
letters[random.randint(0,len(letters))]

my code

```
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) 
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))

letters_password = ""
symbols_password = ""
number_password = ""

if int(nr_letters) <= 50 and int(nr_symbols) <= 50 and int(nr_numbers) <= 50:
 for generator_letters in range(0,int(nr_letters)):
   letters_password += letters[random.randint(0,len(letters))]
 
 for generator_symbols in range(0,int(nr_symbols)):
   symbols_password += symbols[random.randint(0,len(symbols))]
  
 for generator_numbers in range(0,int(nr_numbers)):
   number_password += numbers[random.randint(0,len(numbers))]

else:
  if nr_letters > 50 and nr_symbols > 50 and nr_numbers > 50:
    print("you chose too many letters,symbols and numbers.\n The maximum is 50 of each")
  elif nr_letters > 50 and nr_symbols > 50  :
    print("you chose too many letters and symbols.\n The maximun us 50 of each")
  elif nr_letters > 50 and nr_numbers > 50: 
    print("you chose too many letters and numbers.\n The maximun us 50 of each")
  elif nr_symbols > 50 and nr_numbers > 50:
    print("you chose too many symbols and numbers.\n The maximun us 50 of each")
  elif nr_numbers > 50:
    print("you chose too many numbers, the maximum is 50")
  elif nr_letters > 50:    
    print("you chose too many letters, the maximum is 50")
  elif nr_symbols > 50:
   print("you chose too many smybols, the maximum is 50")



password =(str(letters_password)+ str(symbols_password) + str(number_password))
  
print(password)
```

Comment: For the index range error - you should know that `randint` is `a <= N <= b` so you could get a value that is equal to `len(symbols)` which is of course out of range. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)

Comment: Add a print statement before a line like `letters_password += letters[random.randint(0,len(letters))]` to see what is wrong.

`print("A:::::::", letters[random.randint(0,len(letters))])`

Comment: Do `random.choice(symbols)` instead of `symbols[random.randint(0,len(symbols))]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you're issue is a tiny quirk of the `random.randint()` function. `random.randint()` chooses a random integer between *and including* the first and second parameters that you give it, meaning that it could actually choose the second parameter that you give it as an output. Seeing that `len(symbols)` actually is not an index of symbols, you are bound to run into that `IndexError` on occasion. Each time you call `random.randint()`, subtract `1` from your second parameter and you should be good. For example:

```
symbols_password += symbols[random.randint(0,len(symbols)-1)]
```

Comment: IT WORKS THANKS, BUT I DONT UNDERSTAND! it works, thanks i was thinking was 2 hours, you're answer is the best, you can resolve my code, the other people, was saying me to put random.choice(seq), but you could resolve it! thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the [random module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint):

> random.randint(a, b)
>
> Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for randrange(a, b+1).

So the range includes `len(symbols)`.

Since python uses 0 based indexing, `symbols[len(symbols)]` is an `IndexError`.

Solution: use [random.randrange()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) instead, or subtract 1 from the second argument to randint().

Answer (score 1):

I think what's wrong here that you're trying to use this method *with the string data you have in your lists*

> random.randint() which what it does is : random.randint(a, b)
> ***Return a random integer*** N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for randrange(a, b+1).

So try to use the `random.choice(letters)` method instead.

and refer to [Random library DOCS.py](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#module-random) for more info about the random library

Comment: no brow. the problem is my  len(letters) is 25 ok? but my letters is 0 to 24,  the number 25 doesnt exist,  i put 25- 1, 24 is the last letter, no 25